# Large scale variables in logistic loss

Tags: logistic, error, loss-functions

If I have my the values of my variables are much greater than 1 (i.e. x > 100), than my residuals will probably always be greater than 1 since it is relative. If my cost function is defined is a logistic transformation of the actual minus expected output, then all examples should have approximately the same computed error since below or above the range of $\{-1, 1\}$, the derivative of the logistic function is approximately 0 and the value of the function is about -1  and 1, respectively.

This should be an enormous problem for many ML techniques, but for one, logistic boosting, where the example error serves as an example weight when re-weighting the distribution: It should take an enormous amount of iterations to significantly decrease error.

Yet I have never heard anything about this so I assume I am saying something wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: You are using a language that will be unfamiliar to most readers and likely will be misunderstood by many.  Could you please explain to us what a "large scale variable" is? Whatever it might be, the meaning of your first paragraph is obscure: what is the "logistic error"?  What quantity is "outside the bounds"? Why would this imply "approximately the same"?  What is an "example error"?

Comment: Logistic boosting, which I take to mean gradient boosting regression trees to minimize the logistic loss function, does not re-weight anything explicitly.  So I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: @whuber I hope I made it clearer.

Comment: @MatthewDrury 
 
 
Logistic boosting is different than gradient boosting. Gradient boosting fits trees to residuals. Logistic boosting is a variant of AdaBoost that computes the logistic loss of each example. The resulting value serves as a weight to each example. The distribution is then re-weighted using these weights and the learner at the next iteration learns from this new distribution. It thus focuses on previously misclassified examples. This describes AdaBoost briefly, but very well (it's written by the creators): http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~yfreund/papers/IntroToBoosting.pdf

Comment: Ok then, I don't know much about that version of boosting.  Is it common to use that name for that technique?  What would you call gradient boosting when minimizing the logistic loss?

Comment: Just plain gradient boosting as far as I know, but I do not know gradient boosting so well and at the very least, have never used it in practice.

Comment: I have found it to be superior to adaboost based methods in all aspects, performance, flexibility, and understandability.  My impression of the state of practical boosting is that adaboost has mostly historical importance.

Comment: I think you might be right that AdaBoost's significance comes from being very computationally interesting and may have been top-knotch when it was invented in the 1990s. I appreciate your suggestion about gradient boosting, and will definitely look into it more. Thanks for the help.